# Organising excel cells to a "sparse-ish matrix" with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a few Excel worksheets filled with translation key-value pairs. It has the following columns: **version**, **langcode**, **key** and **value** and it looks like this:

```
2.2 | en-GB | label_yes | Yes.
2.2 | de-DE | label_yes | Ja.
2.2 | de-DE | label_no  | Nein.
```

Not all labels are translated to all languages, and some translations appear more than once. To check it, I'd need a 2D array, where the rows are the keys, the columns are the language codes and the values are the values (so sort of like a *PivotTable*, but with actual values instead of the Sum/Count/Avg), like this:

```
          | en-GB | de-DE
label_yes | Yes.  | Ja.
label_no  |       | Nein.
```

Neither the languages nor the labels are predefined (and there are 4700-ish key-value pairs per file) so I cannot make a sheet with all possible values and some VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP/INDEX/etc magic. Instead, I'd probably need a VB macro that processes the original (input) sheet like this:

- if the *language code* in the current row does not exist yet in the new (output) sheet, copy it to the first available position in the *first row* (B1, C1, D1, etc.)
- if the *key* in the current row does not exist yet in the new (output) sheet, copy it to the first available position in the *first column* (A2, A3, A4, etc.)
- find the column of the *language code* and the row of the *key* of the current row and copy the *value* (content of the fourth cell) to the appropriate position

Unfortunately, this surpasses my near-nonexistent VBA skills. Can anybody provide some pointers where to start? The "how to process a list of unknown length" and the "check if the value if already in the given row/column" parts are a bit hazy (I *think* I can copy a cell... VBA is not my forte. :( ).
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like that:

```
Dim Lan(1 To 5) As String
Dim Value(1 To 1000, 0 To 10) As String
Dim e As Integer
Dim Tmp, Tmp1 As String

Range("F1:M10").ClearContents
e = 1
For i = 2 To 9999
    Tmp = Cells(i, 3).Value
    If Tmp = "" Then Exit For
    tr = False
    For k = 1 To e
        If Tmp = Value(k, 0) Then
            tr = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    tr1 = False
    Tmp1 = Cells(i, 2).Value
    For m = 1 To 5
        If Tmp1 = Lan(m) Then
            tr1 = True
            Exit For
        End If
        If Lan(m) = "" Then Exit For
    Next

    If tr1 = False Then
        Lan(m) = Tmp1
    End If

    If tr Then
        Value(k, m) = Cells(i, 4)
    Else
        Value(e, m) = Cells(i, 4)
    End If

    If tr = False Then
        Value(e, 0) = Tmp
        e = e + 1
    End If
Next

For k = 1 To 5
    Cells(1, 6 + k).Value = Lan(k)
Next
For i = 1 To e
    Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Value(i, 0)
    For k = 1 To 5
        Cells(i + 1, 6 + k).Value = Value(i, k)
    Next
Next
```

Built in memory the Matrix, and rebuilt lateraly.